# jQuery DevExtreme datagrid : Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dxDataGrid is not a function

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, devextreme

I'm having an issue with DevExtreme DataGrid using ASP.NET MVC.

I've downloaded NuGet packages, added script to head section and still have my error :

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dxDataGrid is not a function.

Is there any script to put before? I've just done what the [DevExtreme documentation](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/Getting_Started/Installation/Local_Scripts/) says.

Here's my code.

HEAD:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.5/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

    <!-- DevExtreme themes -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/dx.common.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/dx.light.css">

    <!-- DevExtreme library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/dx.all.js"></script>
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dx.web.js"></script> -->
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dx.viz.js"></script> -->
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dx.viz-web.js"></script> -->
</head>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Output</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div id="gridContainer"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnsubmit").on("click", function () {
            console.log($("#txtTitre").val());
            console.log($("#txtPlot").val());

            if ($("#txtTitre").val() === "" && $("#txtPlot").val() === "") {
                alert("Provide Details to Search !");
            }
            else {
                var obj = {};
                obj.titre = $.trim($("#txtTitre").val());
                obj.plot = $.trim($("#txtPlot").val());

                var apiUrl = "@Url.Action("DataSearch", "AllSearch")";

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    url: apiUrl,
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: JSON.stringify(obj),
                    crossDomain: true,
                    success: function (data) {
                        var response = data;
                        console.log(data);
                        if (data.datasend.length <= 0) {
                            alert("No Data Found!!");
                        } else {

                            var timetook = data.Took;
                            $('div.total-title').text(timetook + " millisecond");

                            $("#gridContainer").dxDataGrid({
                                dataSource: data.datasend,
                                showColumnLines: false,
                                showRowLines: true,
                                rowAlternationEnabled: true,
                                showBorders: true,
                                paging: {
                                    pageSize: 50
                                },
                                scrolling: {
                                    mode: "infinite" // or "virtual" | "infinite"
                                },
                                pager: {
                                    showPageSizeSelector: false,
                                    allowedPageSizes: [5, 10, 20],
                                    showInfo: true
                                },
                                columns: [
                                    {
                                        caption: "Titre",
                                        width: 350,
                                        fixed: true,
                                        dataField: "titre"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        caption: "Plot",
                                        width: 300,
                                        fixed: true,
                                        dataField: "plot"
                                    },
                                     "MaritalStatus",
                                     "Gender",
                                     "SalariedFlag",
                                     "VacationHours",
                                     "SickLeaveHours",
                                     "CurrentFlag"
                                ]
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, err) {
                        alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
                        alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: Have you checked that `dx.all.js` is being loaded correctly? Maybe the path is wrong or something.

Answer (score 1):

Your setup looks to be ok according to this [example](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/SimpleArray/jQuery/Light/).
Seems like there might be a problem fetching that dx.all.js library from your server or your javascript code is run before the needed libraries are loaded! Try to check these possible causes first using your browser's development tools. Look in console/network tabs or make breakpoints at the incriminated line, reload and debug your code to see if the library is really loaded at the needed point.

Comment: this is more of a list of debugging suggestions than an actual solution. Once you have 50 reputation, you'll be able to post comments under questions - what you've written here would be more appropriate as a comment, as it doesn't directly answer the question.